# Proper jQuery image load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.my-image').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).greyScale({
            fadeTime: 200,
            reverse: false
        });
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 1000);
        $(this).load(function(){
            jQuery(this).greyScale({
                fadeTime: 200,
                reverse: false
            });
            $(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 1000);
        });
    });
}, 200);
});
</script>
```

In the above example I use greyScale() function that duplicates image into canvas and keeps both versions (grey = default, color = hover).

It works fine 99% of the time BUT when browser first runs it sometimes fails to load 1 image, 2 images or something like that. It's like both "load" and "normal event" failed to work.

Can someone confirm if I'm doing it right? I attempt to load that event if image is already there or if it's not there then there's alternative "load()" to ensure it will execute once it's loads. Logically it seems like good solution.

Comment: Three very good answers. Each one is helpful. Thank you very much guys! I'm marking the most extensive one as the best but all are really the best here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to test whether an image has loaded or not is to try and access its dimensions, if you can get the height or width of an image, you can assume it has loaded and greyscale it. Therefore you could modify your code to do this:

```
jQuery('.my-image').each(function()
{
    var greyscale = function(image)
    {
        jQuery(image).greyScale({
            fadeTime: 200,
            reverse: false
        });
    }

    if ( jQuery(this).width() )
    {
        // it's loaded, greyscale its ass
        greyscale( this );
    }
    else
    {
        // wait for the load
        $(this).load(greyscale);
    }
});
```

In this situation, since you want the image to be greyscale first I'd recommend inserting images programmatically:

Where your `<img>` tags would be, replace them with `<div>` tags where you add a `data-src` attribute, this will contain the image's URL.

When you're document has loaded, use a script that goes through all the `<div>` tags and insert the `<img>` tags within the `<div>` tags, for example:

```
jQuery('div.my-image').each(function()
{
    var el = jQuery( this );

    // get the src for the image
    var src = el.data( 'src' );

    // start loading the image
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function()
    {
        // greyscale it
        jQuery(img).greyScale({
            fadeTime: 200,
            reverse: false
        });

        // append it
        el.append( img );
    }

    // load the image by setting the src
    img.src = src;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` can be a tricky one, but something like this should work (notice the this.complete check):

```
jQuery('.my-image').each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
        jQuery(this).greyScale({
            fadeTime: 200,
            reverse: false
        });
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 1000);
    });

    if (this.complete) {
      $(this).trigger('load');
    }
});
```

Try to avoid duplicating code, it's not the best of practice.

Comment: You mean `if($(this).complete){ $(this).trigger('load'); }`?

Comment: No, I mean `this.complete`. It's a DOM property, not a jQuery property.

Comment: Will it know that I'm referring to `$(this)` then? Same with `obj`. It just looks like unrelated script :)

Comment: `this` refers to the current *DOM* object (which in your case, inside the `each` loop, is each individual `.my_image` object. `$(this)` wraps that DOM object in a jQuery wrapper so you can bind jQuery functionality to it. If you don't need to use jQuery's functionality on the DOM object, you don't need to wrap it with `$()`. `obj` was a mistake in the code which I've fixed.

Comment: Yes, now everything makes sense with fixed `obj` :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dont rely on `.load()` function for images.

Even jQuery says so .

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser It doesn't
>   fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>   before It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire
>   for images that already live in the browser's cache

Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

If you can , use this,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Images are now loaded for sure
})
```

**Edit:**

or use Paulirish's very lite jQuery plugin

[imageLoaded](https://gist.github.com/268257)