# Sad tomato ( Image .load function in jQuery )

Tags: jquery, image, load, thumbnails

I have a very sad tomato, because it's not resizing, poor thing.  If I don't put the "load" function then some of my thumbs won't resize, and if I do then the other ones won't resize.

```
startDiv.find('img').each(function(p) {
    $(this).parent().css({ height: thumbs_size, width:thumbs_size });
    $(this).css({ height: thumbs_size, width: thumbs_size }); //temporary
    $(this).load(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
            var w = thumbs_size;
            var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * thumbs_size);
        } else {
            var h = thumbs_size;
            var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * thumbs_size);
        }
        $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
    });
});
```

Can anyone save my tomato?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you provide [jsFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem with & without the `load` function?

Comment: The title of your question is meant to be searchable, leave any humor in the question itself, unless you want people who search for sad tomato to find this question.

Comment: A really sad tomato: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/1272/tomatoe2.jpg BTW, checking if an image is load can be tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185390/proper-jquery-image-load

Comment: Nice tomato!  I included my sad tomato in the fiddle.  The Fiddle  shows the problem but not entirely... http://jsfiddle.net/tcHEN/1/  The problem gets worse with more scripting in the page, such as in Wordpress, and with larger image sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because some may already be loaded when you call   `$(this).load(` . Do the following, or something like it

```
startDiv.find('img').each(function(p) {
    $(this).parent().css({ height: thumbs_size, width:thumbs_size });
    $(this).css({ height: thumbs_size, width: thumbs_size }); //temporary

    var $this = $(this);
    function onLoad() {
        var height = $this.height(), width = $this.width();
        var isPortrait = height > width;
        var w = isPortrait ? thumbs_size : Math.ceil(width / height * thumbs_size);
        var h = isPortrait ? Math.ceil( height / width * thumbs_size) : thumbs_size;
        $this.css({ height: h, width: w });
    }
    // Set it on the load event handler in case it's not loaded
    // If it has a width, it's already loaded
    if ($(this).width() > 0) {
        onLoad();
    } else {
       $this.load(onLoad);
    }
});
```

Or you could just use it in the onload handler which guarantees that all images in the DOM are loaded (also all scripts)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    startDiv.find('img').each(function(p) {
        $(this).parent().css({ height: thumbs_size, width:thumbs_size });
        var height = $this.height(), width = $this.width();
        var isPortrait = height > width;
        $this.css({ 
            height: isPortrait ? Math.ceil( height / width * thumbs_size) : thumbs_size,
            width: isPortrait ? thumbs_size : Math.ceil(width / height * thumbs_size) 
        });
    });    
});
```

You may want to give your images default widths and heights with CSS

Comment: This code looks like it should work, and I tried it but some odd results.  Can it be that the width and height of halfway loaded images are getting into the problem?  If you shift-reload in Firefox a few times, you can see that the alert will not always return the same width and height.  Here: http://instancia.net/?p=104

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me, what are you observing? What browser?

Comment: Both browsers do it, randomly either: not resizing images, grabbing the wrong w,h values, etc.  It's hard to see in the Fiddle because it's caching, I think.  Check my page link with shift reload in Firefox (it has your code in it).  Same issue exists outside Wordpress page but the load times are slower in Wordpress so it shows more.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle Another solution is to add everything into the window's load handler, which runs after all the images were loaded, not after the DOM is ready, see edit

Comment: Hmm, suddenly I can no longer reproduce the issue outside Wordpress, so maybe there's a second issue in the jibberish classes Wordpress added to help me out! :)  Let's see if I can remove them...

Comment: Confirmed, the issue exists now only in Wordpress, so I'll go start searching on that.  Your first code fixed the issue outside Wordpress, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Although the solution above worked in any standalone html page, Wordpress just wasn't handling everything the same way, so for Wordpress I used this:

-- Enqueue this javascript in functions.php: 
https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

-- Define your startDiv, for example: startDiv = $(".myThumbnailDiv");.

-- Inside your ready function, add something like:

```
//Thumbnail parent container size, so they load within a thumbsize box
startDiv.find('img').each(function(p) {
    $(this).parent().css({ height: thumbs_size, width:thumbs_size });
});

//Call the function in waitingforimages.js 

startDiv.waitForImages(function() {
   //alert('All images have loaded.');
}, function(loaded, count, success) {

        var height = $(this).height(), width = $(this).width();
        var isPortrait = height > width;
        $(this).css({
            height: isPortrait ? Math.ceil( height / width * thumbs_size) : thumbs_size,
            width: isPortrait ? thumbs_size : Math.ceil(width / height * thumbs_size)
        });
});
```

Comment: PS - I'm not sure if my tomato is happy, but he's round: http://instancia.net/?p=104